# How to use python to convert a backslash in to forward slash for naming the filepaths in windows OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem in converting all the back slashes into forward slashes using Python.

I tried using the `os.sep` function as well as the `string.replace()` function to accomplish my task. It wasn't 100% successful in doing that

```
import os 
pathA = 'V:\Gowtham\2019\Python\DailyStandup.txt'
newpathA = pathA.replace(os.sep,'/')
print(newpathA)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
'V:/Gowtham/2019/Python/DailyStandup.txt'
```

**Actual Output:**

```
'V:/Gowtham\x819/Python/DailyStandup.txt'
```

I am not able to get why the number 2019 is converted in to `x819`. Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is already in `pathA`: if you print it out, you'll see that it already as this `\x81` since `\201` means a character defined by the octal number `201` which is `81` in hexadecimal (`\x81`). For more information, you can take a look at the definition of [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

The quick solution is to use raw strings (`r'V:\....'`). But you should take a look at the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#module-pathlib) module.

Comment: Thanks Francis, Is there a way to avoid the issue with out using the Raw Strings. I will also look in to the string literals and pathlib module. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want to use raw strings, you will need to escape all your backslashes: `'V:\\Gowtham\\2019\\Python\\DailyStandup.txt'`, because in addition to `\ooo`, `\n`, `\t`, and others would also be interpreted by Python. But it also depends on where these strings come from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Using raw `r'your-string'` string format.

```
>>> import os
>>> pathA = r'V:\Gowtham\2019\Python\DailyStandup.txt'  # raw string format                   
>>> newpathA = pathA.replace(os.sep,'/')
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> print(newpathA)                           
V:/Gowtham/2019/Python/DailyStandup.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the raw string leads to the correct answer for me.

```
import os 
pathA = r'V:\Gowtham\2019\Python\DailyStandup.txt'
newpathA = pathA.replace(os.sep,'/')
print(newpathA)
```

OutPut:

```
V:/Gowtham/2019/Python/DailyStandup.txt
```